# Матрица-вектор не транспонируется numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Пользуюсь numpy хочу транспонировать матрицу 1хn.
вот код:

```py
w = np.array([0,0,0,0])
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

print(x)
print(x.T)

print(w)
print(w.T)
```

вывод:

> [[1 2 3]
>
> [4 5 6]]
>
> [[1 4]
>
> [2 5]
>
> [3 6]]
>
> [0 0 0 0]
>
> [0 0 0 0]

Почему "обычная" матрица транспонируется, а "унарная" нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша матрица транспонируется. Вопрос в том, как она выводится на экран. Для того, чтобы увидеть, что матрица транспонирована, сделайте

```
x.shape
w.shape
x.T.shape
w.T.shape
```

Comment: Спасибо, но разве не понятнее сделать вывод [[0][0][0][0]]

Comment: @Some_Person сделайте пулреквест в numpy